# Resource server multiple jwt.issuer-uri

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I want to set the `jwt.issuer-uri` based on the request URL.

Let's say that I have a request `http://hostname/realm1/request` then I want to set the `jwt.issuer-uri` as `http://keycloak-host/auth/realms/realm1`.

If a second request comes from `https://hostname/realm2/request` the the `jwt.issuer-uri` will be `http://keycloak-host/auth/realms/realm2`.

What I did was to create a `SecurityFilterChain` like

```java
@Bean
@Order(100)
public SecurityFilterChain myJwtSecFilterChain (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
        auth.requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
    });

    http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth -> {
        oauth.jwt(jwt -> {
            jwt.decoder(new MyJwtDecoder());
        });
    });

    return http.build();
}
```

And then the decoder:

```java
public class MyJwtDecoder implements JwtDecoder {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyJwtDecoder.class);

    public MyJwtDecoder() {
    }

    @Override
    public Jwt decode(String token) throws JwtException {
        LOGGER.debug("*********** MyJwtDecoder - decode token {}", token);
        return getJwt(token);
    }

    private Jwt getJwt(String token) {

        Jwt result = null;
        List<String> realmList = List.of("realm1", "realm2");
        for (String realm : realmList) {
            JwtDecoder jdLocal = JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation("http://keycloak-host/auth/realms/" + realm);
            try {
                result = jdLocal.decode(token);
                LOGGER.info("TOKEN VALIDATED !!!!!");
                break;
            } catch (JwtValidationException vex) {
                LOGGER.info("Jwt validation exception - Stop Validation - Exception type {} - Message: {}", vex.getClass().getSimpleName(), vex.getMessage());
                throw vex;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // Continue with validation
                LOGGER.info("Jwt validation exception - Continue with other realms validation - Exception type {} - Message: {}", ex.getClass().getSimpleName(), ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

How can I modify the decoder to use the request URL instead of looping into the realms?

The other option could be to create a Filter before `BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter` but in that case how can I bind the decoder?

Please don't give me answers with the deprecated adapters.

Comment: that would be insanely dangerous, as i could create my own malicious issuer and then supply the issuer in the url and your application would blindly just trust it.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your Spring OAuth2 Resource Server to figure out the token issuer automatically based on the "**Issuer Claim**" included in the token.

Here's the code to achieve dynamic issuer resolution

```java
JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver authenticationManagerResolver = JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver
    .fromTrustedIssuers("http://keycloak-host/auth/realms/realm1", "http://keycloak-host/auth/realms/realm2");

http
    .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
    )
    .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
        .authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver)
    );
```

If you need more in-depth configuration options, the Spring Security documentation has excellent explanations: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/multitenancy.html#oauth2resourceserver-multitenancy

Answer (score 0):

You are in a typical multi-tenancy situation.

A JWT decoder is bound to only one JWK set and as so to a single issuer (Keycloak realm in your case).

For this reason, you need an authentication manager capable of keeping several JWT decoders (one per issuer), and delegating the decoding and validation of a token to the right decoder. Usually, the token issuer claim is enough to decide which decoder to use.

If you know all of the Keycloak realms at startup, two options:

- using just official boot starter, follow [the doc linked by @kcsurapaneni](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/multitenancy.html#_resolving_the_tenant_by_claim) and configure the authentication manager in Java conf
- use [my starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/spring-addons-starter-oidc#31-resource-server-with-jwt-decoder) and just list issuers you trust in application properties (no Java conf required in the case of "static" multi-tenancy): just put an entry under `ops` for each Keycloak realm

If you can't know all the issuers you want to trust at startup (because some realms are created at runtime), then you are in a "dynamic" multi-tenancy situation. You can still write the authentication manager yourself, but [my starter definitely requires much less and much simpler code](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/spring-addons-starter-oidc#1-1-4).